# Behaviors are not working properly inside Style Setter

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In my Windows-Runtime app, I have a theme with a style that has a `Behavior` defined for the DoubleTapped action:

These are the XML Namespaces:

```xml
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

And this is the style:

```xml
<Style x:Name="DisplayImage" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="i:Interaction.Behaviors">
        <Setter.Value>
            <i:BehaviorCollection>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
                    <local:ScrollViewerDoubleTap />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:BehaviorCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is my `Behavior`:

```cs
[DefaultEvent(typeof(ScrollViewer),"DoubleTapped")]
public class ScrollViewerDoubleTap : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        ScrollViewer sv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        if (sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility == ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled)
        {
            sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
        }
        return sender;
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using it:

```xml
<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource Image}" MaxWidth="1067">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Image Source="MyImage.png"/>
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When I double-tap the first image on a page that has this style, it works perfectly; however, when I double-tap the other images on the page, the behavior code is never run.  I know it is never run because I ran it with breakpoints, and it would break when I double-tapped the first image, but not the second.  I will appreciate any tips on why this is happening.

Comment: I've also updated the title so it's more specific about what you are asking.

Comment: I've not tried it but I wonder if setting `x:Shared="false"` in your style would solve your problem. i.e : `<Style x:Name="DisplayImage" TargetType="ScrollViewer" x:Shared="false">`

Comment: @franssu `x:Shared` is not available in Windows-Runtime.  Maybe it is a WPF specific control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work because behaviors, actions or triggers are designed to be attached to a *single* element. When you define it inside a style's setter, it's like you are trying to associate it with multiple elements and as you have already seen, the trigger is only called when you interact with the first element with this style.

There's a simple way to fix this. Basically, you need to make sure each element that's associated with this style has a new instance of the trigger you have created. You can have all this logic wrapped inside an attached property and then your style will only need to reference this property.

```
<Style x:Name="DisplayImage" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="local:FrameworkElementEx.AttachBehaviors" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

This is how this attached property is implemented.

```
public static class FrameworkElementEx
{
    public static bool GetAttachBehaviors(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AttachBehaviorsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAttachBehaviors(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AttachBehaviorsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachBehaviorsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttachBehaviors", typeof(bool), typeof(FrameworkElementEx), new PropertyMetadata(false, Callback));

    private static void Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behaviors = Interaction.GetBehaviors(d);

        var eventTriggerBehavior = new EventTriggerBehavior
        {
            EventName = "DoubleTapped"
        };
        eventTriggerBehavior.Actions.Add(new ScrollViewerDoubleTap());

        behaviors.Add(eventTriggerBehavior);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## We can do this using pure XAML

...and a reusable attached property, that receives a `DataTemplate` with a `BehaviorCollection` (or a single `Behavior`).

You don't have to change your code-behind.

```xml
<Style x:Key="SomeImageStyle" 
       xmlns:Behaviors="using:MyBehaviors"
       xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
       xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
       TargetType="Image">
  <Setter Property="local:AttachedBehaviorsEx.AttachedBehaviors">
    <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                        <Behaviors:SomeAction SomeParameter="someValue" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Or if you need a few `Behaviors` at a time:

```xml
    <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <i:BehaviorCollection>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                        <Behaviors:SomeAction SomeParameter="someValue" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                        <Behaviors:SomeAction SomeParameter="someOtherValue" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:BehaviorCollection>
            </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
```

### The attached property

You don't even need to change it.

```cs
using Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using System;

namespace MyBehaviors
{
    public static class AttachedBehaviorsEx
    {
        public static DataTemplate GetAttachedBehaviors(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)obj.GetValue(AttachedBehaviorsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAttachedBehaviors(DependencyObject obj, DataTemplate value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(AttachedBehaviorsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachedBehaviorsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttachedBehaviors", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(AttachedBehaviorsEx), new PropertyMetadata(null, Callback));

        private static void Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BehaviorCollection collection = null;
            var template = (DataTemplate)e.NewValue;
            if (template != null)
            {
                var value = template.LoadContent();

                if (value is BehaviorCollection)
                    collection = (BehaviorCollection)value;
                else if (value is IBehavior)
                    collection = new BehaviorCollection { value };
                else throw new Exception($"AttachedBehaviors should be a BehaviorCollection or an IBehavior.");
            }
            // collection may be null here, if e.NewValue is null
            Interaction.SetBehaviors(d, collection);
        }
    }
}
```

## Why is it better?

It's a more flexible way to achieve this than Justin XL suggested.

His code requires modifying code-behind in order to re-use it. Each time when you want to re-use it, you will need to set the `EventName` (in this line `EventName = "DoubleTapped"`) and the `Behavior` (this line  `eventTriggerBehavior.Actions.Add(new ScrollViewerDoubleTap());`).

Comment: I worked around the problem you mentioned by changing the AttachedBehavior type to string, and passing in the name of the Behavior I want to attach.

Answer (score 1):

Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715798/behaviors-are-not-working-properly-inside-style-setter/29808226#29808226) answer, but for Avalonia, if someone needs it like me.

```
using System;
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Data;
using Avalonia.Interactivity;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.Templates;
using Avalonia.Metadata;
using Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity;

namespace Project.Common.Extensions;

public class AttachedBehaviors : AvaloniaObject
{
    static AttachedBehaviors()
    {
        BehaviorsProperty.Changed.Subscribe(x => HandleBehaviorsChanged(x.Sender, x.NewValue.GetValueOrDefault<ObjectTemplate>()));
    }

    public static readonly AttachedProperty<ObjectTemplate> BehaviorsProperty = AvaloniaProperty.RegisterAttached<AttachedBehaviors, Interactive, ObjectTemplate>(
        "Behaviors", default(ObjectTemplate), false, BindingMode.OneTime);


    private static void HandleBehaviorsChanged(IAvaloniaObject element, ObjectTemplate? behaviorTemplate)
    {
        BehaviorCollection collection = null;
        if (behaviorTemplate != null) {
            var value = behaviorTemplate.Build();

            if (value is BehaviorCollection behaviorCollection)
                collection = behaviorCollection;
            else if (value is Behavior behavior)
                collection = new BehaviorCollection { behavior };
            else throw new Exception($"AttachedBehaviors should be a BehaviorCollection or an IBehavior.");
        }

        // collection may be null here, if e.NewValue is null
        Interaction.SetBehaviors(element, collection);
    }

    public static void SetBehaviors(AvaloniaObject element, ObjectTemplate commandValue)
    {
        element.SetValue(BehaviorsProperty, commandValue);
    }


    public static ObjectTemplate GetBehaviors(AvaloniaObject element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(BehaviorsProperty);
    }
}

public class ObjectTemplate
{
    [Content]
    [TemplateContent(TemplateResultType = typeof(object))]
    public object Content { get; set; }

    public object Build(object data = null) => TemplateContent.Load<object>(Content).Result;
}
```

Then add style (in this example forwards TextBox key press events to validate input in ViewModel):

```
    <UserControl.Styles>        
                <Style Selector="TextBox.Double">
                    <Setter Property="common:AttachedBehaviors.Behaviors">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <common:ObjectTemplate>
                                <i:BehaviorCollection>
                                    <ia:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="KeyDown" SourceObject="{Binding $parent[TextBox]}">
                                    <ia:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleTextBoxKeyDownCommand}"
                                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True">
                                    </ia:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </ia:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    <ia:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="KeyUp" SourceObject="{Binding $parent[TextBox]}">
                                    <ia:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleTextBoxKeyDownCommand}"
                                                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True">
                                    </ia:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </ia:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                </i:BehaviorCollection>
                            </common:ObjectTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>    
    </UserControl.Styles>
```

And finally on the control itself:

```
<TextBox Classes="Double"/>
```