# Move Interaction.Behaviors to Style, Template or something else

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have many XAML TextBlock which looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding InspectionCount}" Style="{StaticResource FilterText}">
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
      <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetModeToAll}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

I want to reduce amount of XAML code and write something like this:

```
<MyTextBlock Text="{Binding InspectionCount}" 
             Style="{StaticResource FilterText}" 
             Command="{Binding SetModeToAll}" />
```

I know only one way to do such things - create the new class (which is inherited from TextBlock), add AttachedProperty (Command) to new class, and create a Style for a new class.

But looks like I cannot inherit my class from TextBlock:

```
public sealed class FilterTextBlock : TextBlock
```

> Cannot inherit from sealed class TextBlock

Why I can not do it? May be there is other way to do what I wish ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have discovered that the following WORKS. and solves the question from many places, I will start answering, Try the following!

```
<Page
x:Class="Example1.ListBoxTest"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Example1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <i:BehaviorCollection x:Key="behaviors">
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetModeToAll}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:BehaviorCollection>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="textblockstyle">
        <Setter Property="i:Interaction.Behaviors" Value="{StaticResource behaviors}">
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <TextBlock Text="Testing" Foreground="Red" FontSize="20" Style="{StaticResource textblockstyle}">
    </TextBlock >
</Grid>
```

It is curious, if I set the behaviors inside the propery i:Interaction.Behaviors does not work but in this way the Command is called!!
Please tell me it works you too!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the behaviours in the static resource can only be attached to one object.  As soon as you attempt to add another TextBlock with the textblockstyle, the same collection would be assigned and throw an InvalidOperationException, or something to that effect.

Comment: Sam Nelson  is right. But you can set the Interaction.Behaviors property in a Style Setter multiple times if you follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808226/1830814

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
<Setter Property="i:Interaction.Behaviors">
    <Setter.Value>
        <i:BehaviorCollection>
            <MyCustomBehavior />
        </i:BehaviorCollection>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

inside the `<Style TargetType="TextBlock">` tag.

Don't forget to include `xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"` at the top of the page.