# uwp define eventriggerbehavior inside style

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm currently stuck with a problem. I want to declare a eventriggerbehavior for all my listviews. this is my code:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource itemShowTemplate}" />
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClicked">
                    <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowItemClickedCommand}" />
                </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Style>
```

the problem I have now is that EventTriggerBehavior is looking for the event on Style and not the targettype of Listview. And the only property left to set on EventTriggerBehavior is SourceObject. But I don't want this behavior on 1 listview, I want it on al my listviews.

Is there a way todo this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behaviors are not working properly inside Style Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715798/behaviors-are-not-working-properly-inside-style-setter)

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808226/1830814

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first idea was that it could work this way:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="i:Interaction.Behaviors">
        <Setter.Value>
            <i:BehaviorCollection>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:BehaviorCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But unfortunately this works only for the first control which gets the behavior attached. The reason is that the value is constructed just once and the `AssociatedObject` property of the `BehaviorCollection` is set to the first control.

I have then come over this solution - [How to add a Blend Behavior in a Style Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter) .
The idea is to create an attached property that manually assigns the behavior to the control.

Based on this I suggest you do it like this:

```cs
public static class ListViewBehaviorAttacher
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAttachedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsAttached", typeof(bool), typeof(ListViewBehaviorAttacher), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), IsAttachedChanged));

    private static void IsAttachedChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var listView = (ListView)dependencyObject;
        //create the binding
        BehaviorCollection collection = new BehaviorCollection();
        var eventTrigger = new EventTriggerBehavior() { EventName = "ItemClick" };
        var invokeCommandAction = new InvokeCommandAction();
        //binding to command
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
            invokeCommandAction,
            InvokeCommandAction.CommandProperty,
            new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("ShowItemClickedCommand"), Source = listView.DataContext });
        eventTrigger.Actions.Add(invokeCommandAction);
        collection.Add(eventTrigger);
        listView.SetValue(Interaction.BehaviorsProperty, collection);
    }

    public static void SetIsAttached(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsAttachedProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsAttached(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsAttachedProperty);
    }
}
```

And then in the style attach it like this:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ListView">
   <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="None"></Setter>
   <Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled" Value="True" /> 
   <Setter Property="local:ListViewBehaviorAttacher.IsAttached" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Comment: this works. Thanks for the help and the great example