# Are `Interaction.Behaviors` supposed to wok in WinUI 3 DataTemplated objects?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winui-3, uno-platform

On Uno Platform project, using several data templates for `TabViewItem`, `TreeViewItem` and `ListViewItem`, trying to fire commands via various events, like `ItemInvoked` (TreeView), `DoubleTapped` (ListView), `CloseRequested` (TabView).

Strangely enough it works for few invocations, then it stops. Note that (also the same) commands bound to Buttons via their `Command` binding continue working.

Example of TabView close attempt. Typically works for first 3 to 5 tabs:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HtmlFileTemplate" x:DataType="local:FileContentViewModel">
            <TabViewItem Header="{x:Bind Info.Name}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Content}" />
                    <!--
                        This just works:
                    -->
                    <Button Command="{x:Bind CloseCommand}">Invoke FileContentViewModel.CloseCommand</Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <!-- 
                    This stops working after few invocations
                    (typically together with all other Interaction.Behaviors bindings):
                -->
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="CloseRequested">
                        <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind CloseCommand}" />
                    </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TabViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:TabsTemplateSelector x:Key="TabsTemplateSelector" HtmlFileTemplate="{StaticResource HtmlFileTemplate}" ... />
    ...

    <TabView TabItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Tabs}" TabItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TabsTemplateSelector}">
    </TabView>
```

I hope, there is some flagrant issue in my usage I can't simply see. Any Help appreciated. Using latest uno stuff (WinUI, dotnet6), debugging on Windows head:

- `dotnet new unoapp -o UnoWinUI3AppName`
- `<PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="7.1.2" />`
- `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.1.3" />`
- `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.1" />`
- `<PackageReference Include="Uno.Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Interactivity.WinUI" Version="2.3.0" />`
- `<PackageReference Include="Uno.Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed" Version="2.3.0" />`

Still trying to find minimal sample exhibiting the mentioned issues.

Also tried to check the XAML generated code, but it is too much... well... generated :-(

**EDIT:**

"Simplified" the use case to following:

- Have `TabView` on a page.
- First tab contains `ListView` with items.
- Other tabs contain "opened" items (dummy record).
- Item opens on double-click (`DoubleTapped`) in `ListView` on first page.
- Item closes on `X` click on a tab (in `TabView`).
- Both `TabView` and `ListView` use `DataTemplate`s.
- Separate UI from code as much as possible (binding, commands, VMs, etc.).
- Based on default WinUI "Hello World" app template.
- [Project files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F8lBht2-NJGnxXFbHm_5wkpguXOxPOoQ?usp=sharing)

**EDIT 2:**
For anyone interested, based on [Andrew KeepCoding's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411960/andrew-keepcoding) hints and linked issue answers, I mixed code behind with custom attaching of the behaviors to the templated items via new attached property:

```
public static class InteractionEx
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachBehaviorsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
    (
        "AttachBehaviors",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(FrameworkElement),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, AttachBehaviorsChanged)
    );

    public static object GetAttachBehaviors(DependencyObject o) => o.GetValue(AttachBehaviorsProperty);

    public static void SetAttachBehaviors(DependencyObject o, object value) => o.SetValue(AttachBehaviorsProperty, value);


    private static void AttachBehaviorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behaviors = e.NewValue switch
        {
            Behavior single => new BehaviorCollection { single },
            BehaviorCollection multiple => multiple,
            _ => null,
        };

        Interaction.SetBehaviors(d, behaviors);
    }
}
```

In XAML the behaviors then can be attached to a control like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ListItemTemplateSelector}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <local:InteractionEx.AttachBehaviors>
        <interactivity:BehaviorCollection>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind OpenCommand}" />
                <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="Open" TargetObject="{x:Bind}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:BehaviorCollection>
    </local:InteractionEx.AttachBehaviors>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem in a plain WinUI 3 project?

Comment: Haven't tried (yet). The idea was to debug on Windows head and then switch to WASM head as a final target (as the direct debug on WASM is a bit unpleasant experience).

Comment: Plain WinUI 3 project behaves the same.

Comment: I created a test app based on your code but I can still execute the ``CloseCommand`` after more than 10 times attempts.  I think that the problem is in how you are closing the tabs. Can you add more code related to that point?

Comment: It is somehow related to the stuff I do in the command handler. When I remove the code, it works reliably (but does nothing :-)). I might (somehow) share the test project, if you are interested. I probably do some of the basic things wrong, because I'm not the UI guy (yet).

Comment: @sharpener -  *ff I do in the command handler* Yeah, very strange. I just started getting exceptions from deep in the WinUI core while executing a command hanging off one of these ugly attached properties. You still looking into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715798/behaviors-are-not-working-properly-inside-style-setter) helpful.

But let me suggest another option. I have spent some time with your repro project and in my opinion, I think it'd be cleaner and readable if you drop **Interaction.Behaviors**. **Code-behind** is not evil if it's UI related and no business logic there.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="TabViewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:helpers="using:TabViewTest.Helpers"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodels="using:TabViewTest.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="BrowserTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodels:BrowserTabViewModel">
                <TabViewItem Header="Browser">
                    <ListView x:Name="ItemList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:ItemViewModel">
                                <TextBlock DoubleTapped="TextBlock_DoubleTapped" Text="{x:Bind Id}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </TabViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodels:ContentTabViewModel">
                <TabViewItem Header="{x:Bind ItemViewModel.Id}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ItemViewModel.Id}" />
                </TabViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>

            <helpers:TabItemTemplateSelector
                x:Key="TabTemplateSelector"
                BrowserTemplate="{StaticResource BrowserTemplate}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TabView
            TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested"
            TabItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TabTemplateSelector}"
            TabItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Tabs}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace TabViewTest.ViewModels;

[ObservableObject]
public partial class MainWindowViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> tabs = new();

    private readonly BrowserTabViewModel browserTabViewModel;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        browserTabViewModel = new();
        Tabs.Add(browserTabViewModel);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void NewTabRequest(ItemViewModel itemViewModel)
    {
        Tabs.Add(new ContentTabViewModel(itemViewModel));
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void CloseTabRequest(ItemViewModel itemViewModel)
    {
        if (Tabs
            .OfType<ContentTabViewModel>()
            .Where(x => x.ItemViewModel == itemViewModel)
            .FirstOrDefault() is ContentTabViewModel target)
        {
            Tabs.Remove(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestions. The "one-time-use" nature of the behaviors was the key issue I wasn't aware of.